# Count the input word in a List in Python

Tags: python, list

[image]
Why my code is not working properly ? It's not counting the word correctly.

Note: The code doesn't needs to be used for.

```
    list1 = input().split(sep=',')
    aim_count = list1.count('Enter aimed word to be counted: ')
    print('The count of aimed word: ', aim_count)
```

Comment: 1) "Why my code is not working properly" is not a good descriptor of the error message. A better descriptor would be "This is what I expect, X and I am getting Y." 2) I advise you to read the documentation on [count](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_count.asp)

Comment: no spaces to be used after the comma

Comment: Try mod: `aim_count = list1.count(input('Enter aimed word to be counted: '))` (i.e. need to input aimed word)

Comment: Please define "word." Seriously, some words are delimited by spaces, but others are delimited by `, ` or other punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting your sentence by `,` but in your input, there is no `,`

Try this:

```py
list1 = input().split()
aim_count = len(list1)
print('The count of aimed word: ', aim_count)
```

Note:
by default `.split()` method splits the sentence by space.

EDIT:
If you want to count the no of a specific word.

try this:

```py
list1 = input().split()

aim word = 'frog'

aim_count = 0
for word in list1:
    if word == aim_word:
        aim_count += 1


print('The count of aimed word: ', aim_count)
```

Comment: It's not working properly anyway bro. As you can see result is still showing 1 when I entered frog two times. I have uploaded image on my post.

Answer (score 2):

```
    list1 = list(map(str.strip, input().split(sep=',')))
    aim_count = list1.count(input('Enter aimed word to be counted: ').strip())
    print('The count of aimed word: ', aim_count)
```

Here you are striping every word obtained from splitting using `str.strip`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to count the number of `frogs` entered

**Input text**: `frog,frog`

#### Code:

```
list1 = input().split(sep=',')
aim_count = list1.count('frog')
print('The count of aimed word: ', aim_count)
```

#### Output:

```
The count of aimed word:  2
```

##### Note:

When the **input** is `frog,cat`, the count of the aimed word is `1`

Also if you want the **aimed word** to be dynamic: you can use this code:

```
list1 = input().split(sep=',')
aimed_word = input('Enter aimed word to be counted:')
aim_count = list1.count(aimed_word)
print('The count of aimed word: ', aim_count)
```

#### Note2:

If you plan to separate the words by comma and a space, then you should be splitting by that delimiter. ie. a comma then a space like this:

```
list1 = input().split(sep=', ')
```

Comment: It's not working properly anyway bro. As you can see result is still showing 1 when I entered frog two times. I have uploaded image on my post.

Comment: No spaces after the comma - should be `frog,frog`

Comment: Okay , thank you it works. This was because of space I think

Answer (score 1):

list's in-build count method takes in the element to be counted, meaning you cannot use `'Enter aimed word to be counted: '` as the element. You'll need to assign the `input()` to a variable and set that as the element to be counted. You'd need to do something along the lines of:-

```
aim_count = list1.count(input('Enter aimed word to be counted: '))
```

You might also be encountering a mismatch due to whitespaces which you can resolve with:-

```
list1 = input().split(sep=',')
list1 = [s.strip() for s in list1]
```

to remove all whitespaces between the words.

Alternatively, you could always use the string in-build count function instead.

```
aim_count = input('Enter sentence: ').count(input('Enter aimed word to be counted: '))
print('The count of aimed word: ', aim_count)
```